# MDX - group dimension by name

Tags: mdx

I have a dimension (page_type) where the names are not unique (so two keys can have the same name). Now I would like to see the clicks by page_type-*name*.
The following query unfortunately show the dimension names, but one line per key.

```
SELECT
{[Measures].[count_clicks]} ON COLUMNS,
[page_type].[page_type].members ON ROWS
FROM  
[customer_journey]
```

The result:

```
category 150.000
product 100.000
category 80.000
...
```

How can I change this query, to get only one line per page_type?

```
category 230.000
product 100.000
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is slow but does this work:

```
with set SetOfPagesWithSameName as
filter
    (
     [page_type].[page_type].members as p,
     p.current.name = [page_type].[page_type].currentmember.name
    )

member Measures.TotalCountOFClicks as
sum(
    existing SetOfPagesWithSameName,
    [Measures].[count_clicks]
   )

member Measures.CountSimilarPagesGrt1 as
IIF(SetOfPagesWithSameName.count > 0 , 1, null)

select 
    NonEmpty([page_type].[page_type].members, Measures.CountSimilarPagesGrt1) on 1,
    Measures.TotalCountOFClicks on 0
from [customer_journey]
```

Comment: Oh right, I pasted an incorrect version from my ssms. gimme a minute

Comment: Somehow it is still not working. CountSimilarPagesGrt1 shows always 1 since SetOfPagesWithSameName.count is always the total number of rows.